# storing my electric lawn mower over winter

Tags: fall-gardening, winter

I live in southern NM where it is dry most of the time, for this winter I must store it outside. Is encasing it in plastic a good idea? Should I cut a slit to let out humidity or water condensation when needed? Or will it just sweat in the plastic and deteriorate?
Thank you for any suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should find some cover place to store it (and your gardening tools). This "hut" do not need to have walls on all sides, but it need to be covered (roof) to protect from rain/snow.

As you wrote, a plastic will create too much condensation, and so it will ruin the engines and other electric parts.  This is less problematic than gasoline engines: gasoline engines tend to heat much more, so the materials are also most subject of rust.

If you do not have a shelter, you may use plastic, but keep a large hole (like a door) on a side, and possibly put some wood stick, so that plastic will not touch your lawn mower (this just to allow circulating air).

If your machine has some batteries (e.g. for starter), you should remove them, and keep them on a warmer place.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the gasoline in a proper container and take it to the dump for proper disposal.  Crank up the engine and allow it to run out of fuel. Throw a tarp over your mower and make sure there is a pallet beneath.  Do not make an air tight covering.  Allow air to flow around your mower. Clean debris under the deck.  Change filters.  Do not use WD40 because that stuff actually attracts moisture.  Use silicon lubricant only. Don't allow the sun to shine on those tires.  Your mower should fare okay.  Better to be inside a garage or shed.  Next season, dump the oil and replace the oil.

Only use NON ethanol gasoline.  Take it to a shop and hang out and talk to the guys while you are able.  Check to see if I am right.  Make that shop your best friend.  Have your blades sharpened and always have an extra set of sharpened blades to change out blades as soon as you see the tops of the blades of grass becoming chewed up.

If you can keep dirt out of that engine that engine will last forever.  Well, that is what they told me and at least those engines do a great job an awful lot longer.

Comment: gasoline on an electric lawn?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  What did I miss this time? Oh good golly, an electric MOWER?  in the dang title.  I give up...

Comment: The title of the question is about electric lawn, which should not have gasoline